# Haskell newbie: Return type mismatch

Tags: haskell

I ran into a roadblock trying to figure out why I can't compile the following code. I'm defining several functions to work with a "snoc" list. the headS works properly but in the tailS function, I cannot return a NilS and I was wondering why. I know this might be a very basic issue but I have already tried googling yet I got more confused. Hope you can help me understand what am I missing. Here's my code:

```
data ListS a = NilS
          |Snoc (ListS a) a deriving Show

headS :: ListS a -> a
headS NilS          = error "Empty List"
headS (Snoc NilS a) = a
headS (Snoc a b)    = headS a

tailS :: ListS a -> a
tailS NilS          = error "Empty List"
tailS (Snoc NilS a) = NilS
```

I get the following error:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `ListS a0'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      tailS :: forall a. ListS a -> a
    at Ejercicio01.hs:9:1-21
* In the expression: NilS
  In an equation for `tailS': tailS (Snoc NilS a) = NilS
* Relevant bindings include
    a :: a (bound at Ejercicio01.hs:11:18)
    tailS :: ListS a -> a (bound at Ejercicio01.hs:10:1)
   |
11 | tailS (Snoc NilS a) = NilS
   |                       ^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Thanks in advance for your time,

Comment: Well you specify that the output list is a `NilS`, but `NilS` is *not* an `a, but a `ListS b` (with `a` possibly different than `b`) type.

Comment: Much appreciated. It makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the compiler is correct. The type signature of your function is:

```
tailS :: ListS a -> a
```

So the output type should be an `a`. But here you write as return value `NilS`. Now `NilS` is a data constructor of the `ListS a` type. So the two do not match: your signature says that you will return an *element* of your "list" type, but in the function definition, you return a list (that might actually wrap elements of another type).

What you probably want is to return the `a` element, and not an `NilS`, so:

```
tailS :: ListS a -> a
tailS NilS = error "Empty List"
tailS (Snoc NilS a) = a
```

But there is still another problem. If we compile it with `-Wincomplete-patterns`, then the compiler will tell that there is a pattern that is *not* covered: the `Snoc (Snoc _ _) _` pattern. In your last line you write `tailS (Snoc NilS a)`, so you restrict it to the first item of the `Snoc` being a `NilS`. This is not necessary, regardless of what the "prefix list" is, the tail is always the second parameter, so we can fix this with:

```
tailS :: ListS a -> a
tailS NilS = error "Empty List"
tailS (Snoc _ a) = a
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer Willem! I totally missed that last part of the constructor. Truly appreciate your help and the insights offered. I just realized it is possible to expand the warnings we get while trying to compile the code by using additional commands. 

Again, thank you and hope you have a great weekend.